# Unable to add / remove Event Reminder using Google Apps Calendar v3 API

Tags: java, events, google-calendar-api, reminders

I am trying to update an event in a Google Calendar: change the color and remove or add event reminders. I can easily update the color, but I can't find a way to remove the default reminder, or even add a new one. 
Here is my code:

```
    Event googleEvent = client.events().get(cal, events.getItems().get(i).getId()).execute();
    ArrayList<EventReminder> listEventReminder = new ArrayList<EventReminder>();
    Reminders reminders = googleEvent.getReminders();
    reminders.setUseDefault(false);
    EventReminder reminder = new EventReminder();
    reminder.setMethod("popup");
    reminder.setMinutes(42);
    listEventReminder.add(reminder);
    reminders.setOverrides(listEventReminder);
    googleEvent.setColorId("10");
    googleEvent.setReminders(reminders);
    client.events().update(cal, googleEvent.getId(), googleEvent).queue(batch, callback);
```

The color of the event is properly updated (to green) however, the reminder is still set on "popup 10 min"